# What is your suggestion for Bug Tracking or bug database?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-applications, bug-tracking

In our company, when we get a report of a bug, we fix it.  After a while it can happen again, but by then we've forgotten the reason and fix it again.  It's like we are in loop of bugs.

This is because we have a dynamic data application that is configurable for each customer and the bugs are mostly because of data.  So my question is how should we keep the bugs' history including how we fixed them, and then search and use the bug history to fix similar bugs?

I don't even know which keyword I should search for.

Comment: Use a bug tracking application like Atlassian JIRA or Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a very good comparison article on issue / bug tracking systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source or free tools where you can maintain the bugs list. 
Few of them that I know are, Double Chocolate, BugZilla, JIRA etc...
Google out you will get many of them. And offcourse there are some paid tools as well.

You can search for "Issue Tracking Tools" or "Bug tracking tools."

The link below is pretty old, but still you can find many of them 
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bug-tracking-system/

Answer (score 0):

I have experience in using Bugzilla, and Fogbugz for tracking bugs. Both are good.

Bugzilla(open source) is a Web-based general-purpose bugtracker and testing tool originally developed and used by the Mozilla project.

FogBugz is an integrated web-based project management system featuring bug/issue tracking, discussion forums, wikis, customer relationship management, and evidence based scheduling.

Comment: thanks @nikhil.I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Boto](http://www.botoapp.com) for tracking bugs.